# error while using multiple if else function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

i am relatively new to r, i want to Write a function, calCS, to perform the following task:
 Calculate the area of a circle (AC = pi*r^2), the circumference of a circle (CC = 2*pi*r), the volume of a sphere (VS = (4/3)*pi*r3 or the area of a sphere (AS = 4*pi*r^2)
. The first argument is either AC, CC, VS, or AS to determine which calculation needs to be performed
. The value that the first argument takes can contain either lower, upper, or mixed cases of letters
(Use the toupper function)
. If the values of the argument are not AC, CC, VS, or AS, stop the function and write
❵your method is not supported✬
. The second argument is the radius (r). Make sure to use if ... else statements for this problem.
i have tried using multiple if else statement but got the same error related to parenthesis again and again.

```
calCS <- function(x,r){
if(x="AC"){
a <- pi*r^2
print(a)
} 
} else {
  if(x="CC"){
b <- 2*pi*r
  print(b)
}else {
  if(x = "VS"){
  c <- (4/3)*3.14*(r^3)
  print(c)
}else {
  if(x = "AS"){
  d = 4*pi*(r^2)
  print(d)
}
}
}
}
```

got Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: You should look at using `else if (x == ....)`. Also, this seems like a better candidate for `switch`.

Comment: Also, this reads suspiciously like a homework problem (though those are not necessarily off topic here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems.

1. You're not using `else if` correctly.
2. `=` is not the same as `==`.

Other areas for improvement (even sticking within the confines of having to use `if` and `else`) is that your function is not very DRY. You have four `print`s in there, while one would suffice. Also, indentation helps a lot with readability.

---

Here's a dummy function to get you started. You obviously know how to define your functions and print them, so you can do the substitution from there:

```
calCS <- function(x, r) {
  if (!x %in% c("AC", "CC", "VS")) stop("Your method is not supported")
  if (x == "AC") {
    sprintf("I am a cat with %s toes", r)
  } else if (x == "CC") {
    sprintf("I wish I had %s toes", r)
  } else if (x == "VS") {
    sprintf("I just counted %s toes", r)
  }
}
```

Example of the function in action:

```
calCS("AC", 3)
# [1] "I am a cat with 3 toes"
calCS("CC", 3)
# [1] "I wish I had 3 toes"
calCS("VS", 3)
# [1] "I just counted 3 toes"
```

And, if there's an unsupported method:

```
calCS("rat", 3)
# Error in calCS("rat", 3) : Your method is not supported
```

---

I'll leave the integration of `toupper` and any other error checking for you since that is not related to `if else`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
calcCS <- function(x, r) {
  print_and_return <- function(x) { print(x); x }
  print_and_return(switch(x, AC = pi * r^2, CC = 2 * pi * r,
                             VS = (4/3)*3.14*(r^3), 4*pi*(r^2)))
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like `if else` to me. You didn't read your homework properly :-)

Comment: I can do what I want!

Comment: While you are doing what you want, why did you want to define a function called `print_and_return`? Wouldn't that print the output twice to the console?